# python boost scope cause NoneType error

Tags: python, c++, boost

I've compiled a third-party python module （`alembic`）, alembic import another python module （`imath`） by `PyImport_ImportModule`, imath import another python module (`iex`) again by `PyImport_ImportModule`. The codes like:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(alembic)
{
    handle<> imath(PyImport_ImportModule("imath"));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(imath)
{
    handle<> iex(PyImport_ImportModule("iex"));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(iex)
{
    scope().attr("BaseExc") = "An Exception";
}
```

It works if I import imath first, then import alembic. But if I import alembic directly, it will raise a NoneType error at `scope().attr("BaseExc") = "An Exception"`. I've read the boost code, and I'm sure the reason is `detail::current_scope` is empty, but I don't know why.

Can any one help me about it? Why it was happened and how can I avoid it?

Add:

I can't reproduce it by the code above. I wrote a cpp file and fill it by these codes:

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(alembic)
{
    handle<> imath(PyImport_ImportModule("imath"));
}
```

Then use this option to compile it:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-soname,alembicmodule.so -o alembicmodule.so alembic.cpp
```

And it works fine. I'm surprised because in the third-party module, the error happened at the first line. Maybe this is not a boost bug, it is a cmake bug?

Comment: You'll have to provide an MCVE, as per site guidelines. Also, your formatting is a bit broken.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Where is broken? All the formatting looks fine. And I'm trying to reproduce it without boost, if I'm succeed, I will provide the MCVE.

Comment: The first paragraph seems broken.

Comment: OK, I've added all the information I had. I can't reproduce it by my script, that's so confused.

Comment: Check the `#define` for `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`, I could imagine that this can only be used once per Python module.

Comment: I've checked the definition of ``BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE``, and this macro has only two branches —— one branch is used to support python2/3, another branch is used to support windows/linux. I'v tried to add some output statement into the definitions, nothing different.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I meant that it could be impossible to define multiple Python modules in one C++ binary! Also note that you write about importing modules, but that macro actually defines and rather exports the according modules!

Comment: Ummmm... Sorry, my misunderstanding. I use ``grep -r BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`` at per module folder, yes, it only appear once.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, you will have to take the long road and reduce your original code to the smallest code that still reproduces the issue in order to post that here.

Comment: Yeah... I'm doing it now. If I find any discovery, I will put it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes from compiling options. Cmake generates a link script, and this script use `libboost_python.a` to link the python module `alembicmodule.so`. When I change `libboost_python.a` to `libboost_python.so`, this issue was fixed.